# Manual trigger sharepoint list items bulk approval

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint List consists of monthly created 30 to 50 over items, I want to get external approver's approvals, which referred to email column, for last calendar month created line items (according to date column).

Initiators/users may not be able to finish key in all line items timely, hence, scheduled flow will not work.

How can I allow initiator/user to manual trigger the approval and send email with html table to external user, without manually select item by item?

Comment: In the Filter Query field, enter the following expression: Created ge '@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-daysInMonth(utcNow())),'yyyy-MM-dd')}' and Created le '@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}'
This expression will filter the items that were created in the last calendar month based on the Created column.

Comment: How about the manual trigger mechanism?